# How to make a class member big 2D C array properly?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have a very simple piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

const int K=1;
const int N=1024*K;
const int M=1024;

class C {
  public:
  C(){
    minstd_rand0 g(1);
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) for(int j=0; j<M; ++j)
        a[i][j]=generate_canonical<float, numeric_limits<float>::digits>(g);
     }
  private:
  float a[N][M];
};

int main()
{
  C c;
  cout<<"size="<<N*M/(1<<20)<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

At K=1 the code works, but at K=2 immeadiately fails with a segmentation fault.
So, as I understand, there is some restriction on the amount of data an arbitrary class can contain (not more than this amount of MB). How to get to know this amount exactly?

In my work I deal with arrays similar to *a*, which stand for the probability function distribution on some line segment. I have dozens of such arrays. I supposed to put all these arrays in 1 manager class that will handle all of them, but as this example shows, it is impossible, a segmentation fault occurs. So, I have for example 10 arrays (I would like to incapsulate all of them inside some single object) of double's with the number of elements 2x1024x1024. How to manage them in the program properly?

P. S. If to allocate them on the heap:

```
class C {
  public:
  C(){
    p = new float*[N];
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) p[i]=new float[M];
    minstd_rand0 g(1);
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) for(int j=0; j<M; ++j)
        p[i][j]=generate_canonical<float, 
                numeric_limits<float>::digits>(g);
  }
  ~C(){
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) delete [] p[i];
    delete [] p;
  }
  private:
  float ** p;
};
```

the program works even at K=100. Is it a proper way to manage them?
After all, is there a way to allocate the array statically without making it a *static* class member?

P. P. S.
This piece of code works:

```
const int K=10;
const int N=1024*K;
const int M=1024;
float a[N][M];

class C {
  public:
  C(){
    p=(float *)a;
    minstd_rand0 g(1);
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) for(int j=0; j<M; ++j)
      p[i*M+j]=generate_canonical<float, 
               numeric_limits<float>::digits> 
               (g);
    }
  public:
  float *p;
};
```

But I don't know if it is a proper way to hande such big arrays.

Comment: When dealing with exceedingly large data, you'll want to heap allocate it. Automatic storage is not really meant to be used for data of this magnitude, which would account for the problem you're experiencing. There's no specific hard limit on how much automatic memory you're given (it'll depend on operating system and possibly your processor architecture) but it's not meant to be pushed to the limit.

Comment: For a modern OS on a desktop computer expect between 1 and 10 MB of automatic storage. For an embedded system all bets are off.

Comment: Since your "manager" class is single by nature you can use `static float a[N][M];` and the problem will be gone. Faster and simpler than the heap. `static` storage counts in GBs, assuming your `K` <= ~200 you won't run it out.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I can't use static class members. I use OpenAcc to compile the code for launching it on GPU. OpenAcc does not allow to use static class members.